# background image is not full width in PDF after upgrading from wkhtmltopdf-0.12.5 to wkhtmltopdf-0.12.6

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I have a page:

```
<div id="g-rapport-power-particulier_2020_5-Garde_Recto" class="page">
    <img id="g-rapport-power-particulier_2020_5-Garde_Recto-img" class="g-aiImg" alt="" src="{{ pathToWeb }}/images/rapport/cover_2020.jpg"/>
    <div id="g-ai0-1" class="g-Layer_1 g-aiAbs g-aiPointText" style="top:10.5863%;margin-top:-23.1px;left:50.9119%;margin-left:-185.5px;width:371px;">
        <p class="g-pstyle0">xxxxxxxx</p>
    </div>
    <div class="prospectContactDetails">
        <p>{{ project.prospect.firstname }} {{ project.prospect.lastname }} - {{ project.prospect.address.street }} {{ project.prospect.address.postalCode }} {{ project.prospect.address.city }}</p>
        <p>{{ project.prospect.email }} - {{ project.prospect.phone }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.page {
                position: relative;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                page-break-after: always;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 21cm;
                height: 29.7cm;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

        #g-rapport-power-particulier_2020_5-box .g-aiImg {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            display:block;
            width:100% !important;
        }
```

that I want to convert in pdf with `wkhtmltopdf`. In version 0.12.5, image were displayed in full width.

Now I just upgraded to 0.12.6, and now it have a right margin about 25% more than original.

There is so many [issues](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues) on this component it is quite hard finding informations on the repo.

I couldn't find any upgrade guide.

Any idea how should I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to a version change  I can get exactly the same result in 0.12.4 or 0.12.5 or 0.12.6 the undefined defaults cover image placement is on the left but the borderless one on the right has a defined set of PDF document borders as zer0 wide.

[image]

One change that I did find between versions is due to security that images need to be allowed for local access

```
wkhtmltopdf -T 0 -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 --enable-local-file-access wkhtml.html output.pdf
```

For a cover page you really should be using the coverpage option as described in `wkhtmltopdf --readme` and/or `wkhtmltopdf --manpage`
since that allows a separate page definition for your cover compared to the settings for TOC plus Outline and body of the document.